# Some datalabels do not show on highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I have a highcharts example where I can combining three charts.  yAxis 0 has two series and is a column chart, yAxis 1 is a line chart, and I have a pie chart as series 4 floated off to the side.

It is fairly complex.  Yet everything translates except for the datalabels.  They fall out for some reason.  It is always the same datalabels falling out.

**Here is my code:**

```
$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        zoomType: 'xy',
        marginLeft: 300
    },
    legend: {
        align: 'left',
        verticalAlign: 'top',
        layout: 'vertical',
        x: 60,
        y: 10,
        floating: true
    },
    xAxis: [{
        opposite: true,
        categories: ['Chicago', 'Dubuque', 'Omaha', 'De Pere', 'St. Louis', ]
    }, {
        categories: ['Week 17 2015', 'Week 18 2015', 'Week 19 2015', 'Week 20 2015', 'Week 21 2015', 'Week 22 2015', 'Week 23 2015', 'Week 24 2015', 'Week 25 2015', 'Week 26 2015', 'Week 27 2015', 'Week 28 2015', 'Week 29 2015', ]
    }],
    yAxis: [{
        labels: {
            align: 'right',
            x: -3,
            enabled: false
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Compliance Percentage'
        },
        height: '50%',
        //lineWidth: 2
    }, {
        labels: {
            align: 'right',
            x: -3,
            enabled: false
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Non-compl Events'
        },
        top: '55%',
        height: '45%',
        offset: 0,
    }],
    series: [{
        name: 'Percent compliance',
        type: 'column',
        data: [92, 88, 62, 87, 80],
        xAxis: 0,
        yAxis: 0,
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            inside: true
        }
    }, {
        name: 'YTD compliance',
        type: 'column',
        data: [91, 72, 66, 81, 75],
        xAxis: 0,
        yAxis: 0,
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            inside: true
        }
    }, {
        name: 'non-compliant events',
        type: 'line',
        data: [31, 38, 42, 45, 88, 57, 42, 38, 56, 61, 55, 56, 54, ],
        xAxis: 1,
        yAxis: 1,
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true
        }
    }, {
        type: 'pie',
        fillOpacity: 0.1,
        name: 'Total consumption',
        data: [{
            name: 'ANDERSON, KE',
            y: 4
        }, {
            name: 'HOWARD, DP',
            y: 2
        }, {
            name: 'KNAUB, RD',
            y: 4
        }, {
            name: 'PIQUE, DC',
            y: 7
        }, {
            name: 'WEBSTER, JT',
            y: 6
        }, {
            name: 'Total',
            y: 18
        }],
        center: [-175, 100],
        size: 200,
        showInLegend: false,
        dataLabels: {
            connectorWidth: 1,
            distance: -25,
            borderRadius: 5,
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(252, 255, 255, 0.5)',
            borderWidth: 1,
            formatter: function () {
                return this.point.name + ' ' + this.y;
            },
        }
    }]
});
```

**Here is my fiddle:** [Highchartsjs with 4 series. 1 Pie, 2 Columns, 1 Line](http://jsfiddle.net/franktudor/c33L58gv/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a bug to me, but I may just not be understanding the overlap calculations.  Setting allowOverlap to true for the series will make them all show up

```
   {
        name: 'non-compliant events',
        type: 'line',
        data: [31, 38, 42, 45, 88, 57, 42, 38, 56, 61, 55, 56, 54, ],
        xAxis: 1,
        yAxis: 1,
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            allowOverlap: true
        }
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/c33L58gv/1/

BTW, nice looking visualization.

Comment: Thank you very much on the compliment. :) I have added your overlap fix and it worked!